# Start downloading on Notification bar click in android

Tags: android, notifications

My code shows notification bar and when I click on that it starts downloading. Only problem is it goes to the browser and starts there. I want that download starts but it doesn't go to browser. My code is :

```
Intent NotifyIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse(ApkFileLocation));

                PendingIntent  intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(EnquireActivity.this, 0, NotifyIntent, 0);
                NotificationDetails.setLatestEventInfo(context, ContentTitle, ContentText, intent);

                mNotificationManager.notify(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID, NotificationDetails);
```

Answer (score 0):

By setting `NotifyIntent` to `android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW` with a URL, you are telling the system, "I don't care how this is opened, so use the default behavior."

If you want the download to happen in the background you should implement a `Service` and write code to download the file there. Then have `NotifyIntent` point to a `BroadcastReceiver` which will start the `Service`. The service should be able to display the download status in the notification bar as an "ongoing" activity (can't be dismissed).

**EDIT:** It looks like you can start the Service directly using an Intent in this manner:

```
Intent NotifyIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, NotifyIntent, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks @mtmurdock what I should write instead of android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW?

Comment: Lemme clear what I exactly looking for. I have put apk file. So whenever there is a new update notification should appear, which appears. Then on click on notification it should start downloading new update. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Yes, you should be using the Google Play store to distribute your app so you don't have to push out updates in this manner.

Comment: I can't. Because this application is for embassy and it has confidential data. So I don't want anyone to download and install it.

Comment: Then use my above method. When the download is complete you should be able to put another notification to the user with an intent to open the .apk (which will launch the package installer).