# Start a download when click a notification in android

Tags: android, download, notifications

I want to put a notification in android top bar, and when user click on it, downloadmanager will start download the file. How to set the pendingIntent for this notification?

Answer (score 0):

[Android Notifications - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNotifications/article.html)  will definitely help you achieve what you want.

An excerpt of what you want from that is below. You can call the following function:

```
  public void createNotification(View view) {
    // Prepare intent which is triggered if the
    // notification is selected
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiverActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

    // Build notification
    // Actions are just fake
    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setContentTitle("Title")
        .setContentText("Subject").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
        .setContentIntent(pIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "Call", pIntent)
        .addAction(R.drawable.icon, "And more", pIntent).build();
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // Hide the notification after its selected
    noti.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify(0, noti);

  }
```

For starting the download manager, you might have to adjust the function accordingly. Check the tutorial link for detailed understanding. Also there are other relevant answers which might help:

[Start downloading on Notification bar click in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11633545/start-downloading-on-notification-bar-click-in-android)

[Android how to start an apk download from the notification drawer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16479087/android-how-to-start-an-apk-download-from-the-notification-drawer)

[open file on click of notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14874468/open-file-on-click-of-notification)

[Opening activity after clicking push notification android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10308710/opening-activity-after-clicking-push-notification-android) question.

Hope this helps.